# Is it acceptable to use in the word "opening" in the following context?

Tags: sentence-construction

In my university there is Psychology course in English medium, can I tall them the next sentence?

What do you think about the using of "opening" in this case. Also, what do you think about the tense that I have used it in this sentence (present progressive).

"In case that you are **opening** a new discipline in English Medium , kindly let me know about it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting your sentence with "In case that", I'd probably use "when".  The phrase "in case" has a slight emergency connotation when used in a leading position:

> **In case** of fire, break the glass!
>   **In case** of water landing, pull lever to deploy raft. *et cetera*

You want to be made aware of the beginning of the new course so you can take part in it, right?  Perhaps you should add that to your request:

> When you are opening a new discipline in English Medium, kindly let me know about it, please.  I'd like to consider taking that course.

And, maybe restructure your request a bit to put the point forward.  You're interested in English Medium, so say:

> When there is a new discipline in English Medium, I'd like to know to consider taking it.  Is there a way you could notify me, please?

But you have started with a very sufficient statement, and use of Present Continuous tense is quite appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. 
But, the issue is that I don't know if they will have something like that in the future. That's why I wrote "In case of..." Maybe I can change it to "If the college opens a new discipline in English Medium, kindly let me know about that"

Comment: Yes, you could use "if", but "when" contains the implied condition, as well, that's why I suggested it.  It also has a positive note of expectation and belief in college's growth, whereas both "in case" and "if" put forward some kind of doubt, uncertainty.